# Excel formula for assigning a Client to a Sales Rep

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to figure out the proper Excel formula to review a list of client names in Column A and compare them to a Sales Rep name in Column B to subsequently assign that Client to the Sales Rep they've worked with the most.  Using the below as an example, I'd like the formula to review the data and return the result (in Column C) that Joe Smith is assigned to Jane Doe because he worked with her more than the other people.

```
Client Name Sales Rep
Joe Smith   Jane Doe
Joe Smith   Jane Doe
Joe Smith   Jane Doe
Joe Smith   Jim Jones
Joe Smith   Jim Jones
Joe Smith   Bill Johnson
Joe Smith   Jack Reynolds
```

My data is sorted first by Client Name and then by Sales Rep.  The purpose for this is that I'm reviewing potential new business from our Clients and I want to alert the proper Rep, rather than having the notification go to one of the other Reps.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the formula isn't simple, but this *array formula* at at column `C` does it:

```
C2:
=INDEX($B$2:$B$110,
  MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$110,A2,$B$2:$B$110,$B$2:$B$110)),
  COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$110,A2,$B$2:$B$110,$B$2:$B$110),0))

  Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

p.s. you might have more than 110 rows; adjust accordingly but **dont use A:A and B:B** because the formula would become *very slow*.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know countifs could digest arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a unique excel formula could do this. VBA will do the job.

However you could also make a pivot table out of your data.

Put client name and Sales Rep in rows and Number Of Client name in values.

[image: pivot]